# Existence of solution in Hölder spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Let's say we have a PDE, for example the Laplace equation:
$$
\Delta u = f.
$$
Usually, to solve such a thing, one finds its variational formulation, and solves it in some Sobolev space.

My question is, is it possible to avoid the weak formulation, and find solutions directly in Hölder spaces? Maybe via some fixed-point argument?

Comment: Try reading Lectures on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Hölder Spaces by N.V. Krylov (edited by the AMS).

Answer (score 1):

A good book to start is [Gilbard-Trudinger](http://books.google.ch/books?id=eoiGTf4cmhwC&pg=PA87&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) chapter 6. Also take a look in [Brezis](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uni.wroc.pl%2F~karch%2Fanaliza_nieliniowa%2Fref%2FBREZIS__Functional_Analysis__Sobolev_Spaces_and_Partial_Differential_Equations__Universitext_.pdf&ei=vkI8UsfxGJGA9gT6soCQDQ&usg=AFQjCNGP9nqQmNf4F1EOrBbb_glm25twWQ&sig2=VXYIgXdCP9n62gvgE0ZfyA) book. After Theorem 9.33 (Schauder), he makes a comment where he gives a plenty of references about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure one can find the solution in the continuous or Holder spaces. Way out is that we have the fundamental solution (Newton Potential) E(x,ξ) for Laplace equations, one solution to such nonlinear PDEs when f=f(x,u) or f=f(x,u,∂_i u)   is given by 
u^*=∭_Ω E(x,ξ) f(ξ,u(ξ),∂_i u(ξ))dξ    in a bounded set Ω ⊆ R^3
Which can be easily verified to be in the C^(1,α) (Ω)-space